# Como abrir ficheiros .txt em Python?

Tags: python

Eu quero abrir um ficheiro .txt para leitura mas o python dá sempre erro, quer use

```
f = open('ficheiro.txt', "r")
```

ou

```
f =open('C:\...(diretório)...\ficheiro.txt', "r")
```

Já criei ficheiros a partir do python para saber onde eles são guardados e colocar lá o ficheiro que quero, e mesmo assim não funciona. Apenas dá quando copio o conteúdo que quero para o ficheiro que crio com o python, mas dá muito trabalho.

O python levanta sempre este erro:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ficheiro.txt'
```

O que posso fazer para resolver o problema?

Comment: O ideal seria que voce colocasse o codigo real (ctrl-c, ctrl-v) e a mensagem do erro no corpo da sua pergunta, da forma que vc escreveu ficou muito abrangente, dificil de entender qual é o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Hugo, esse erro é devido ao Python não localizar o arquivo no local onde você está tentando abrí-lo. Logo, o arquivo não está no mesmo local onde você está executando o script. Por exemplo, se seu script Python estiver na raiz do drive C, o arquivo .txt deverá estar lá também, caso não seja especificado seu caminho.

Answer (score 1):

A *flag* `"r"` dá erro se o arquivo não existir.

Para evitar o erro, use `"a+"`:

```
f = open('ficheiro.txt', "a+")
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Mas ele quer abrir o arquivo para leitura, se ele não achar o arquivo para abrir, mesmo que não apresente o erro, ele não vai conseguir fazer o que precisa já que não terá acesso ao conteúdo do arquivo.

Comment: Aí é questão de negócio do programador.

Comment: Cara, somente leitura... O cara só quer ler o que está no arquivo, o único objetivo em abrir é ler o seu conteúdo. Kkk

Comment: Ué, se a resposta não está boa, você pode responder também. É melhor que ficar argumentando aqui.

Comment: Já responderam certo aí encima

Answer (score 0):

consigo abrir o arquivo de qualquer lugar e mostra-lo na tela desta forma:

```
f=open("C:\Users\usuario\Downloads\Telefones.txt",'r') #caminho do arquivo
file_data = f.read() #variavel que receberá o arquivo escolhido
print file_data
```